# Sending location via text

Tags: java, android, listview, gps

I'm Having a problem with sending my location coordinates to my cellphone.

**Here is the code of Main.Java**

```
    package com.example.finder;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.telephony.SmsManager;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Main extends Activity {

TextView textLat;
TextView textLong;
TextView textAlt;

public String onLocat;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkin);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

            String ALT = extras.getString("wysokosc");
            String SPE = extras.getString("speed");

            sendSMS("09164232662", "wys" + " " + ALT + "   " + "spee" + " - "
                    + SPE);
        }


    });

    textLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLat);
    textLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLong);
    textAlt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textAlt);

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener ll = new mylocationlistener();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
}

class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            double pLong = location.getLongitude();
            double pLat = location.getLatitude();
            double pAlt = location.getAltitude();
            String PPro = location.getProvider();

            textLat.setText(Double.toString(pLat));
            textLong.setText(Double.toString(pLong));
            textAlt.setText(Double.toString(pAlt));


            Intent i = new Intent(Main.this,
                    Main.class);
            i.putExtra("wysokosc",Double.toString(pLat));
            i.putExtra("speed",Double.toString(pLong));
            startActivity(i);

        }

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}

private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage("09164232662", null, message, null, null);
}

}
```

**Here is the code of GPS.Java**

```
package com.example.finder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class GPS extends Activity {
Button checkout;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gps);
    checkout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkout);
    checkout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

            String ALT = extras.getString("wysokosc");
            String SPE = extras.getString("speed");

            sendSMS("09164232662", "wys" + " " + ALT + "   " + "spee" + " - "
                    + SPE);
        }

    });
}

// ---sends an SMS message to another device---
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
}

}
```

**Here is the code of Manifest File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.finder"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.example.finder.GPS"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Here's the logcat**

```
02-02 14:27:03.619: D/libEGL(10290): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
02-02 14:27:03.629: D/libEGL(10290): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
02-02 14:27:03.629: D/libEGL(10290): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
02-02 14:27:03.634: D/(10290): Device driver API match
02-02 14:27:03.634: D/(10290): Device driver API version: 10
02-02 14:27:03.634: D/(10290): User space API version: 10 
02-02 14:27:03.634: D/(10290): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16     15:37:13 KST 2012 
02-02 14:27:03.659: D/OpenGLRenderer(10290): Enabling debug mode 0
02-02 14:27:05.309: D/AndroidRuntime(10290): Shutting down VM
02-02 14:27:05.309: W/dalvikvm(10290): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x411b72a0)
02-02 14:27:05.314: E/AndroidRuntime(10290): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-02 14:27:05.314: E/AndroidRuntime(10290): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-02 14:27:05.314: E/AndroidRuntime(10290):    at     com.example.finder.Main$1.onClick(Main.java:36)
02-02 14:27:05.314: E/AndroidRuntime(10290):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
02-02 14:27:05.314: E/AndroidRuntime(10290):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
02-02 14:27:05.314: E/AndroidRuntime(10290):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-02 14:27:05.314: E/AndroidRuntime(10290):    at     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-02 14:27:05.314: E/AndroidRuntime(10290):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-02 14:27:05.314: E/AndroidRuntime(10290):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
02-02 14:27:05.314: E/AndroidRuntime(10290):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-02 14:27:05.314: E/AndroidRuntime(10290):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-02 14:27:05.314: E/AndroidRuntime(10290):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
02-02 14:27:05.314: E/AndroidRuntime(10290):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
02-02 14:27:05.314: E/AndroidRuntime(10290):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-02 14:27:16.474: I/Process(10290): Sending signal. PID: 10290 SIG: 9
```

The problem is it's getting the signal yet it does not send through my cellphone.

Let me know what wrong I am doing.

Comment: is there any logcat ?

Comment: are you getting the coordinates perfectly ?

Comment: Have you added the `SEND_SMS` permission?

Comment: Sorry i'm new to stack overflow and i'm not that familiar with posting codes so i had to do it 1 by 1.

Comment: try adding a `Log.v("Intent Extras", ALT + SPE );` right after `String SPE = extras.getString("speed");` to make sure you're getting the intent extras correctly.

Comment: the log cat is there,

Comment: @tuga i did what you said but it still does the same
and whenever i run the app, it tells finder(application) has stopped, then when i click ok that's when it tells SENDING SIGNAL. PID 10290 SIG:9

Comment: is main activity your first activity?? are you sending this extras to main activity??

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener ll = new mylocationlistener();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
    final String ALT = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER).getLatitude();
    final String SPE = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER).getLongitude();

    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkin);


    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            sendSMS("09164232662", "wys" + " " + ALT + "   " + "spee" + " - "
                    + SPE);
        }


    });

    textLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLat);
    textLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLong);
    textAlt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textAlt);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a conceptual problem in your application. First, you have defined two entry points in your manifest, it should be something like:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.example.finder.GPS" />
```

And then your CPS is quite useless, where you call it?

And whay you call the same activity?

Intent i = new Intent(Main.this,
                Main.class);
        i.putExtra("wysokosc",Double.toString(pLat));
        i.putExtra("speed",Double.toString(pLong));
        startActivity(i);
Just define pLong, pLat and pAlt as global and use them inside your onClick to send the sms.

Hope this helps.